# SQLite Creating Table Dynamically

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I have a table in SQLite and when an entry is made in this table, I would like to create a new table for each entry in the first table. (I want to do this in Ruby On Rails, if that helps)

Here is an example to clarify what I am trying to achieve:

Assume there is a table: Campaigns

**Campaigns**

Campaign_ID, date, name

So if I make an entry:

01 06/12 FirstCampaign

is there a way to create a new table called: {Campaign_ID}_Page

i.e:

**01_Page**

(fields for this table go here)

Comment: Sure, just send the appropriate CREATE TABLE into the database. The real question though is why are you trying to do such a thing?

Comment: Having one Page table becomes enormous after a lot of campaigns are added with their pages. I am trying to limit the size of the page table for each campaign. Please let me know if you know of a more clever way to do this. I know my solution isn't clever haha.

Comment: It seems like you want a separate table linked to every record of the campaigns table? Have you considered MongoDB?

Comment: Yes that seems to be what I am looking for. I will look up MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need it?

I think it would be better to create a table Pages with a foreign key to your table Campaigns.

An example (I use Sequel):

```
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.sqlite

DB.create_table :Campaigns do 
    primary_key :id
    column  :campaign_id, :integer
    column :date, :date
    column :name, :string
end

DB.create_table :Pages do 
    primary_key :id
    foreign_key :campaign_id, :Campaigns
    column :text, :string
end

key = DB[:Campaigns].insert(:campaign_id => 01, :date=> Date.new(2012,1,1), :name => 'FirstCampaign')
DB[:Pages].insert(:campaign_id => key, :text => 'text for FirstCampaign')

key = DB[:Campaigns].insert(:campaign_id => 02, :date=> Date.new(2012,1,1), :name => 'SecondCampaign')
DB[:Pages].insert(:campaign_id => key, :text => 'text for SecndCampaign')

#All pages for 1st campaign
p DB[:Pages].filter(
  :campaign_id => DB[:Campaigns].filter(:campaign_id => 1).first[:id]
).all
```

---

But to answer your question: You could try to use a [model hook](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/model_hooks_rdoc.html).

An example with Sequel:

```
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.sqlite

DB.create_table :Campaigns do 
    primary_key :id
    column  :campaign_id, :integer
    column :date, :date
    column :name, :string
end


class Campaign < Sequel::Model
  def after_create
    tabname = ("%05i_page" % self.campaign_id).to_sym
    puts "Create table #{tabname}"
    self.db.create_table( tabname ) do
      foreign_key :campaign
    end
  end
end

p DB.table_exists?(:'01_page')  #-> false, table does not exist
Campaign.create(:campaign_id => 01, :date=> Date.new(2012,1,1), :name => 'FirstCampaign')
p DB.table_exists?(:'00001_page') #-> true Table created
```

My example has no test, if the table already exist. If you really want to use it,